# Is Python-based software considered less-professional than C++/compiled software?

Tags: c++, python

I'm working on a plugin for some software that I'm planning on selling someday. The software I'm making it for has both a C++ SDK and a Python SDK.

The C++ SDK documentation appears incomplete in certain areas and isn't documented that well.

The Python SDK docs appear more complete and in general are much easier to work with.

So I'm trying to decide if I want to go through the potential trouble of building a C++ plugin instead of a Python plugin to sell. About the only thing that makes me want to do a C++ plugin is that in my mind, a "C++ plugin" might be an easier sell than a "Python plugin". A lot of programmers out there don't even considered writing Python to be real "programming".

Do you think that potential customers might say "Why would I pay money for a measly little Python script?"?  As opposed to "Oh it was written in C++ so the guy must be a decent programmer"?

Writing the Python plugin would be faster. Both plugins would look and behave exactly the same. The C++ plugin might be faster in certain spots, but for the type of plugin this is, that's not a huge deal.

So my question is, would a Python plugin be considered not as professional/sellable as a C++ plugin, even if it looks and acts EXACTLY the same as a C++ plugin?

Comment: This doesn't seem to *really* be about programming. It's guessing about about the mentality of the potential customers for your plug-in. If you gave some information on (for example) the software for which you're writing the plug-in, and the nature of the plug-in itself we might have at least some basis for a guess, but as-is we don't even have sufficient information to speculate. Even with that information, it still wouldn't be about programming though.

Comment: But nonetheless, it is an interesting question, and I have personally run into this "Python is not real/professional/etc." Stack Overflow's audience is probably the correct audience to ask this, so I'd let it go. I'd also community-wiki it, as it is quite a subjective question.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed as the FAQ clearly states that you can ask questions that are "matters that are unique to the programming profession". I thought SO was a great place to ask a question like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> A lot of programmers out there don't even considered writing Python to be real "programming".

A lot of "programmers" out there are incompetent, too.

> Do you think that potential customers might say "Why would I pay money for a measly little Python script?"?

I'm sure it depends on the type of software, but I can tell you that my program's customers have little interest in what we use to develop our product, and I doubt most of them know that the software is written in C++.  They just care that it works.

> So my question is, would a Python plugin be considered not as professional/sellable as a C++ plugin, even if it looks and acts EXACTLY the same as a C++ plugin?

No.

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't matter. It all come down to 'use the right tool for the right job'. Your primary goal should be to make the best plugin you can. So if you feel more at ease with Python use that. It will probably take you less time to write. The client probably doesn't mind it and just want the most stable, reliable, cheapest, easiest to use plugin. So concentrate on that not on the tool.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of answer is appropriate for this question, it seems to deserve more of a marketing answer than a technical answer. If your customer is not someone who would be knowledgeable about the differences between languages, or even what a programming language is, then why mention it?

But if your customer is knowledgeable, and if your plugin delivers real value and does something useful, I don't see why it should matter. I will admit that there is something to what you're saying: years ago I had the option of buying a license for a Javascript widget toolkit, and I had the same reaction you are describing: why would I pay this?

That wasn't the right reason to reject that toolkit: the right reason was to reject it because of the number of freely available and well-supported alternatives. So, to repeat myself: if your plugin does something new, valuable and not otherwise available (or not easily available), then push it on those merits instead of which language you've written it in.

Some very complex software is written in Python, from the [Listen media player](http://www.listen-project.org/) to [YouTube](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2006-December/070323.html).

Finally, if you didn't know, there are ways of [distributing compiled PYC files](http://effbot.org/zone/python-compile.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Python will also have the advantage/disadvantage (depending on what you want) that the source code must be open. (I think delivering only the `.pyc` file is not really an option as the Python bytecode format is changing in every release.)

Otherwise, let's say you are selling to people who don't really know what the difference is between Python/C++: The outcome is the important thing. If your Python plugin runs and feels stable and fast, it is fine.

If they have heard about both languages, there really may be a difference. I must admit, if I had a choice between two plugins which do exactly the same and which are perfectly stable from all user reports, I probably would prefer the C++ plugin. It would be my intuition which would tell me that the C++ code is probably slightly more stable and faster. This is also for Unix tools and other stuff.